# Eclipse 3.5 Cache Problem

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, spring

I am using eclipse 3.5 with google app engine + spring framework to develop application. My problem is when I change the code and build the project, the new code doesn't come in to effect. I even deleted the old file but at runtime, the old version gets display in the browser. Why?

Comment: are you developing files for a web-project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the similar issue and the problem was due to not stopping the running server.

What i was doing was running the server, editing the java file, saving and again running the server. This created two instances of the server running and when checking into the browsers the old code was executed from the first instances.

So, the solution is terminate and relaunch the server, and your new changes will be in effect.

Comment: Thanks this was the problem I had had

Answer (score 1):

Your description is not explicit, so following are my assumptions:

- You are changing jsp/js or view related files
- You have Google app engine plugin for eclipse to deploy the code

Following might be one of the reasons:

- Your view files are cached in the browser, so try deleting the browser cache
- Google app engine might have cached your files, so try deleting the temp folder
- Eclipse IDE wouldn't have deployed your changed code, so check the timestamp, if it still shows the old timestamp, then find out how to configure eclipse to detect your changes.

Answer (score 1):

I found 3 workarounds for similar issue (changes to a servlet (.java file) were not taking effect).

1. Before editing the .java file, stop the application. It seems that if you edit it while running, the issue occurs, even if you edit it, stop then re-start.
2. Delete items in Temp folder e.g, (C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp), then stop and re-start the app.
   I think the culprit folder in the Temp folder is this:Jetty_127_0_0_1_8888_war_*_*.g0qk00
3. Right click in in the console area and select 'Remove All Terminated'. Sometimes that reveals there are other instances running, which need to be stopped by clicking the terminate button.